# Cyanogen run clean breakfast

Tags: android, build-process, cyanogenmod

I have intentionally aborted the "breakfast codename" command because it was taking too long looking for dependencies.

Now when I run the breakfast again this not seek for dependencies and I not see the files needed to run "extract-files.sh" and I do not see the need to run in vendorsetup.sh, when trying to run vendorsetup gives me error that fails the folder ../../vendor/xx

How to safe rerun breakfast for codename and dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run repo sync and breakfast again

```
repo sync -f -j16 -c
breakfast codename
```